# Newbie: Using $mod method during insert in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, modulo

I'm sure this is the easiest question for you, but forgive me for being naive.
I have been trying to learn mongodb and wanted to experiment with some aggregation.

For that, I wanted to insert data into a collection like this.

for (i=1; i<=10; i++) { db.aggtest.insert( {a : { $mod: [i, 3]}, b : i}) }

However this doesn't seem to work. I have tried using it for update as well, but it gives a different error for me.

Please help me with this.

Thanks
Radha

Comment: Either you wrote your insert incorrectly on this question, or you have an extra '}' after '[i, 3]'

Comment: Yes forgive me, its incorrect in the question, but it doesn't even if I have the correct ones.

Comment: This is what I have tried for (i=1; i<=10; i++) { db.aggtest.insert({ a: { $mod : [i, 3] }, b : i}) }

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that, otherwise you might get responses that don't answer your question.

Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks, this is the error I get.

Comment: Error: field names cannot start with $ [$mod] :... Edited my original post as well, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $mod operator is used for queries and projection.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/

For your javascript function use the language specific operator for insertion:

```
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) { db.aggtest.insert( {a : i%3, b : i}) }
```